# Python: How to insert tab and format text file

Tags: python, split, format

Bringing in a text file that is formatted like below:

```
hammer#9.95
saw#20.15
shovel#35.40
```

I need to bring it into python and format it so that it is in line with an existing snippet of code:

`# display header line for items list
print('{0: <10}'.format('Item'), '{0: >17}'.format('Cost'), sep = '' )`

The goal is for the text file to be in line with existing headers like so:

```
Item   Cost
hammer $9.95
saw    $20.15
shovel $35.4
```

I can bring in the text file into Python and get replace the # sign with a $ sign:

```
file = open('Invoice.txt', 'r')
file_contents = file.read()
new_file_contents = file_contents.replace('#', '$')
```

Which gives me this output:

```
hammer$9.95
saw$20.15
shovel$35.40
```

but I'm having trouble with the formatting aspect. Any suggestions?

Comment: I think the str split or partition methods would be useful for this task. Once you split each line, then you can use the formatting command at the top of your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
with open(file,'rt',encoding='utf-8') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        print("{:<6} {}".format(line.strip().split('#')[0],"$"+line.strip().split("#")[1]))
```

only problem is that it'll look ugly if you have a longer word than hammer. I suggest finding the largest word in your list first, then using that as the limiter for the {:<6}.